# Regex: match string that doesn't contain only zeros

Tags: regex

I need a regex that matches any string that doesn't contain only zeros.

Examples
Match:

```
123
012
3210
01210
0aaasdf1230
aa a f sbbaasdf0as
()asd as 0 asd%#%0
```

Don't Match:

```
0
00
000
0000000000000
000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Any 0 AND space so ?

Comment: So you've tried nothing and you're all out of ideas?

Comment: Depending on the language you are using, there are alternative (sometimes faster and usually more readable) ways to do this.

Comment: I would do `^[0\s]*([^0\s][0\s]*)+$`

Comment: I would do `[^0]`.

Comment: @melpomene He wants to match the whole string

Comment: @Leyffda I don't think so. But even then, `.*[^0].*` would do it.

Comment: I used (?!0).*    , but it doesn't match 012

Comment: .*[^0].* works perfect, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lSXqVJ/1)

```
^(?!0*$).*$
```

matches exactly any string which is not 0*. (the last `$` is redundant because * quantifier is greedy)